# Java Draw Rectangle method

Tags: java, graphics

So when we are drawing a rectangle in java

```
g.drawRect(X, Y, 100, 10);
```

Is the rectangle formed from the top left corner and goes 100 units to the right and 10 down, or is there a center (X,Y) which extends 50 units to the left and right and 5 units to the top and bottom?

Comment: What about a circle, how does that work?

Comment: Perhaps you should try reading the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawOval(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rectangle is formed from the top left corner and goes 100 units to the right and 10 down

Comment: I know you're right, but can you sight evidence for that claim ;)